# Web scraping only getting half the items with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get all the article titels from [this](https://www.zalando.nl/herenschoenen/) page.

All the 84 items I want have the same class name:

"cat_brandName-2XZRz cat_ellipsis-MujnT"

This is my code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib


url = "https://www.zalando.nl/herenschoenen/"

soep = BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen(url).read(), 'lxml')

#trying to get all objects with the article tag, which should be 84 items.
articles = (soep.body.find_all("article"))


for x in articles:
    try:
        print(x.find(class_="cat_brandName-2XZRz cat_ellipsis-MujnT").get_text())
    except:
        continue
```

But the results only give me 35 out of the 84 items:

```
Nike Sportswear
Nike Sportswear
Nike Performance
Nike Performance
adidas Originals
Nike Sportswear
Clarks Originals
Nike Sportswear
Nike Performance
Nike Sportswear
Nike Sportswear
Nike Sportswear
Puma
Lacoste
Clarks Originals
Vans
Nike Performance
Birkenstock
adidas Originals
adidas Originals
Reef
adidas Originals
New Balance
Nike SB
Levi's®
adidas Originals
Lacoste
Tommy Hilfiger
New Balance
Reebok Classic
Bugatti
Birkenstock
```

When i save the webpage to my device as a Chrome HTML document and use that in my code it works and I get all of the article titels.

But I don't want to download the pages, and there probably is a way to do it with urllib.
(With requests.get() it's the same problem)

Comment: I haven't used Beutiful Soup, but from what you're saying, saving the webpage interactively has more content than the page as downloaded from Beautiful soup. I think that perhaps the page adds content after initial download from the server using Javascript. It's very difficult to scrape pages that aren't static without incorporating a browser. The Selenium test framework would allow you to wait until some items appear in the page because it can interact with a running web browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the API is probably the best way to solve it, however you can do this with the help of `selenium` as well. The reason you don't get all the results is that all of content in the webpage is not loaded when you open it first. Make sure you install chromium webdriver and put it in your path.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.zalando.nl/herenschoenen/"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driverPath)
driver.get(url)
html_content = driver.execute_script('return document.body.innerHTML')
soep = BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'lxml')

articles = (soep.body.find_all("article"))

for x in articles:
    try:
        print(x.find(class_="cat_brandName-2XZRz cat_ellipsis-MujnT").get_text())
    except:
        continue
```

Comment: This worked for me, thanks.

Now I am also curious as to what API is and how I could use that.